# Does changing your folder's name affect Vercel deployment?

Tags: vercel

So about a month ago I deployed a NextJS website project to Vercel and it was successful. I've been updating that website ever since and it was all normal until today.
For some reason, all my deployments are unable to proceed, they stay at "Queued" and just...well stay like that.
[image]

I've looked it up but I don't know what's the problem here.
Couple hours ago I did one minor change to the *folder* contains my website project.
My website project is stored inside another folder. I renamed that folder couple hours ago and I think that's possibly the issue here? (I know it sounds silly but I'm new to programming so anything is possible to me)
The way I renamed the folder was simply right-click > Rename. Maybe that way of doing is incorrect so It caused a trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after like 2 hours of queueing, my site is finally updated and everything is back to normal again.
All I changed was 1 line of code, still don't know why it took so long for Vercel to update it.
This silly question is closed

Comment: While it's great that you have found the answer to your original question, maybe you can provide exactly what was changed in case someone has a similar situation?